# Selenium Webdrive better than direct request?

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse some Facebook pages using BeautifulSoup to get verification sentences "Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand." data-tooltip-position="right"
that suggest the page is verified. I feed Beautiful Soup with source code from direct request and from Selenium Web Driver Separately, but can only succeed with later:

I firstly tried source code from request:

```
 import requests 
 response = requests.get(url)
 content = response.content
```

Then I use BeautifulSoup to parse the content and search for the sentence. I tried with different parsers like html.parser, xml, lxml, html5lib, with no finding:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') 
 elements = soup.find_all(
 attrs={
   "data-tooltip-content": 
   "Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand."
 })

 elements
 []
```

So instead I tried using Selenium Web Driver to get the html source code and feed it to BeautifulSoup, and this time I can get the text successfully:

```
from selenium import webdriver
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser') # also used xml, lxml, etc, same results
elements = soup.find_all(
attrs={
   "data-tooltip-content": 
   "Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand."
 })
```

and I got the following, which is just what I need.

```
[<span class="_56_f _5dzy _5d-1 _3twv _33v-" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand." data-tooltip-position="right" id="u_0_bd"></span>,
 <span class="_56_f _5dzy _5dzz _3twv" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand." data-tooltip-position="right" id="u_0_b0"></span>,
 <span class="_56_f _5dzy _5dzz _3twv" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand." data-tooltip-position="right" id="u_0_b1"></span>,
 <span class="_56_f _5dzy _5dzz _3twv" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand." data-tooltip-position="right" id="u_0_b2"></span>,
 <span class="_56_f _5dzy _5dzz _3twv" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand." data-tooltip-position="right" id="u_0_b4"></span>]
```

To learn more contexts, I used regex to pinpoint `_56_f _5dzy _5dzz _3twv` and print nearby texts to see if the sentence I need is in the source code.

```
import re
re.findall(r".{100}_56_f _5dzy _5d-1 _3twv _33v-.{100}", response.text)
```

and got the following, with no target sentence:

```
['u003Cspan class=\\"_3d2h\\">\\u003Cspan data-hover=\\"tooltip\\" data-tooltip-position=\\"right\\" class=\\"_56_f _5dzy _5d-1 _3twv _33v-\\" id=\\"u_0_bb\\">\\u003C\\/span>\\u003C\\/span>\\u003C\\/div>"},2],["__markup_072b8e64_0_0",{"__html":"\\u0']
```

with html (returned by selenium web driver):

```
re.findall(r".{100}_56_f _5dzy _5d-1 _3twv _33v-.{100}", html)
```

and got:

```
['1></span></span><span class="_3d2h"><span data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-position="right" class="_56_f _5dzy _5d-1 _3twv _33v-" id="u_0_bd" data-tooltip-content=

"Verified PageFacebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for th*',

'3Cspan class=\\"_3d2h\\"&gt;\\u003Cspan data-hover=\\"tooltip\\" data-tooltip-position=\\"right\\" class=\\"_56_f _5dzy _5d-1 _3twv _33v-\\" id=\\"u_0_bd\\"&gt;\\u003C\\/span&gt;\\u003C\\/span&gt;\\u003C\\/div&gt;"},2],["__markup_072b8e64_0_0",{"']
```

I'm not familiar with the front end tools and wonder what is the cause of the different outcome, and also if there is a way for me to get the complete BeautifulSoup parsed tree without using Selenium web-drive? Thanks!

Comment: also tried changing the `User-Agent` in request as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755849/python-getting-html-content-via-requests-returns-partial-response, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that the html is generated using javascript. If you view the html source code you can see Verified is there, it's just inside the data of the javascript.

```
["__markup_d3c2dfe2_0_0",{"__html":"\u003Cdiv class=\"_4ag8\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_50f7\">Verified Page\u003C\/div>\u003Cspan>Facebook confirmed this is an authentic Page for this public figure, media company or brand.\u003C\/span>\u003C\/div>"},1]
```

view-source:https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/

If you do not want to use selenium I'd recommend searching the request text for Verified.

```
requests.get(url).text.find('Verified')
```

It works in selenium because the browser executes the javascript to build the html.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I do want to get the whole sentence, so looks like interpreting javascript form is inevitable.